# How do I make text spanning multiple lines each have each letter vertically aligned in CSS?

Tags: css, webfonts

How do I make text spanning multiple lines, have each letter vertically aligned in CSS?

I have set the following using CSS.

```
word-spacing: 0px;
padding: 0px;
letter-spacing: 24px;
```

I think the mis-alignment is happening because I'm not using a monospaced font.

Is there a way to force all the characters in a font to be the same width to make things easier? All so they can all be vertically aligned when spanning multiple lines?

[You can try out the code here.](https://jsfiddle.net/desbest/ws5oh1Lc/1/)

[image: diagonal-grid-paper-for-reference-for-stack-overflow.gif]

---

For future reference I've copied the code below.

HTML

```
<div class="gridpaperfocus">
    <p>paragraph one</p>

    <p>paragraph two</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  font-family: Tahoma;
}

.gridpaperfocus {
    background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/HezKKmn.png');
    background-color: #dcdcdc;
    /* font-weight: bold; */
    /* max-height: 100px; */
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-style: double;
    margin: 16px;
    /* color: rgb(255, 153, 51); */
    color: #3c3c3c;
    padding: 0px 30px;
    /* padding: 0px; */
    word-spacing: 0px;
    margin-left: 32px;
    letter-spacing: 24px;
    line-height: 30px;
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
}


.gridpaperfocus p {
    margin: 0px;
    margin-top:  0px;
    margin-bottom: 30px; /* 42px with gridpaperback.png */
}
.gridpaperfocus p:last-of-type { margin-bottom: 0px; }
```

Comment: Provide some code.

Comment: @disinfor I've added the code with a jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using a monospace font isn't possible then one way would be to wrap each character in a span element and force that to have a fixed width and the character to be centered within it.

Not very elegant and you'd want to employ some preprocessing rather than do it by hand - could be done fairly simply in Javascript.

Here's a trivial snippet with a couple of wide characters and a narrow one to show the idea:

```css
span {
  width: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<span>A</span><span> </span><span>i</span><br><span>i</span><span>A</span><span>X</span>
```

Comment: I've managed to upload a code sample. Can you see if you can get it working using my jsfiddle link? https://jsfiddle.net/desbest/ws5oh1Lc/1/

Comment: You need to write a bit of Javascript to put a span element around every character (including any spaces or punctuation mark)

Comment: Thank you. I've got it to work now. I've had to add a `margin-left:` and `max-width:` to the span tag. https://jsfiddle.net/desbest/73e2tq5a/